# white space after absolute element

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with white space after an absolute span in a relative container div, white space is with no effect, but in case it is replaced with white space Unicode (which is &nsub), IE renders it successfully.Although I have tested it FF and it the result was the same.
More details:
I am using win7 OS
Ie 8

ANd this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div style=" display:inline;position:relative;">
    <p>
    <div style=" display:inline;position:relative;">

    <span style=" display:inline;position:absolute;">x</span>    y

    </div>
    </p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When i fiddle this, I see a y on an x. What do you want instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace is indeed meaningless in HTML and to force space you can use the HTML entity `&nbsp;`.

To have the text appear to the right of the span you can make that `span` float instead of absolute positioned:

```
<span style="float: left;">x</span>
```

Then you can set its right margin to decide exactly how much space to put, for example:

```
<span style="float: left; margin-right: 15px;">
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/fg8NF/

Comment: Thanks a lot Shadow Wizard :)  this fixed my problem